# IE8, HTML5, and combined classes ala .class1.class2{}

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, quirks-mode

I'm making a responsive site and periodically do stuff like this:

```
.someclass {}
.someclass.with_context {}
```

IE8 doesn't recognize the second class. IE9 does.

I'm using the HTML5 doctype and it's using IE8 Standard Mode as page default.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try isolating your issue - try making a normal HTML4 doctype HTML file, and using the CSS selectors. Does it work there? If so, it's probably the HTML5 doctype and IE8 not cooperating.

Comment: Probably you did a syntax error and IE9 is omitted it, double check your code.

Comment: Send a link to live demo so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/5690-multiple-class-id-selectors/) has a good article on using multiple Classes/IDs.  From what I've read, it's supported by most browsers (including IE7 - Not IE6).

Of course, [QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html) has a quick article on it too.

If you're using HTML5, are you using [Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) ([headjs](http://headjs.com/), or [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), or some other way for the [CSS to recognize the HTML5 elements](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/))?

Can you put an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Or is this just a typo?

Is your HTML like this?

```
.someclass {}
.someclass.with_context {}
<div class="someclass with_context">Hello World</div>
```

or is it like this?

```
.someclass {}
.someclass .with_context {}
<div class="someclass">
<div class="with_content">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You may need to make your HTML5 elements block level:

```
header,nav,article,footer,section,aside,figure,figcaption{display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll follow up if I ever get a few minutes to track down the details of the behavior, but here's what I sorted out:

As we all knew, IE8 really does support

```
.myClass.anotherClass {}
```

just fine.

Facebook used to require you use

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

to use Like buttons and the like. This caused some very strange edge case behavior, and switching to their "HTML5"/javascript like-modules makes it extraneous.

The thing that finally did it - and the interesting part - is that some of the uses were inside media queries, which seems to matter. When I have more time to test and track them down I'll follow up here with details.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It supports the class specifier with/without the space but there are two different meanings but I've forgotten what the difference is without the space.

Comment: Correct. Space means anotherClass is a parent element. No space means these properties apply to elements that have both classes on them.

Comment: Actually JasonG01, with a space it means anotherClass points to a child element of myClass, no the other way around.

Answer (score -2):

Im assuming you mean your css

something like this

```
<article class="someclass">

    <section class="with_context">something here</section>


</article>
```

note the above could use standard divs instead of HTML5 tags

either way your CSS needs a space between the 2 classes

```
.someclass {SOME CSS}   
.someclass .with_context {SOME CSS}
```

Comment: Would be true, but actually w0lf42 had the intent right. HTML looks like <div class="someclass with_context">.